# Android Generate QR code and Barcode using Zxing

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

Code to generate  Qr code using zxing is ---

It takes string data and the `imageview` This works just fine

```
private void generateQRCode_general(String data, ImageView img)throws WriterException {
    com.google.zxing.Writer writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    String finaldata = Uri.encode(data, "utf-8");

    BitMatrix bm = writer.encode(finaldata, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,150, 150);
    Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(150, 150,Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {//width
        for (int j = 0; j < 150; j++) {//height
            ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK: Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    if (ImageBitmap != null) {
        qrcode.setImageBitmap(ImageBitmap);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.userInputError),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

Now my question is ,how to get `bar code` using the same library.i saw some files related to `bar codes` but i am not sure how to do it.
Since I want to generate the `bar code` within the application and not call any `web service`. Since i am already using zxing,no point in including *itext*  and *barbecue jars*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using QRCodeWriter. If you want to write another type of code, use another Writer.

Check this [MultiFormatWriter](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/MultiFormatWriter.java) - it can write any type of bar or find specific writers [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing) in subfolders (this is from zxing library)

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm.i am pasting the code... mite help someone in the future'

Answer (score 11):

Like Gaskoin told... MultiFormatWrite it worked :) here is the code.

```
      com.google.zxing. MultiFormatWriter writer =new  MultiFormatWriter();


        String finaldata = Uri.encode(data, "utf-8");

        BitMatrix bm = writer.encode(finaldata, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,150, 150);
        Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(180, 40,Config.ARGB_8888);

        for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {//width
            for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {//height
                ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK: Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        if (ImageBitmap != null) {
            qrcode.setImageBitmap(ImageBitmap);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.userInputError),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

I've tested the accepted answer to generate a Barcode but the output is **blurry** when used in a big ImageView. To get a high quality output, the *width* of the BitMatrix, the Bitmap and the final ImageView should be the same. But doing so using the accepted answer will make the Barcode generation really slow (2-3 seconds). This happens because

```
Bitmap.setPixel()
```

is a slow operation, and the accepted answer is doing intensive use of that operation (2 nested for loops).

To overcome this problem I've modified a little bit the Bitmap generation algorithm (only use it for Barcode generation) to make use of Bitmap.setPixels() which is much faster:

```
private Bitmap createBarcodeBitmap(String data, int width, int height) throws WriterException {
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    String finalData = Uri.encode(data);

    // Use 1 as the height of the matrix as this is a 1D Barcode.
    BitMatrix bm = writer.encode(finalData, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, width, 1);
    int bmWidth = bm.getWidth();

    Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmWidth, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < bmWidth; i++) {
        // Paint columns of width 1
        int[] column = new int[height];
        Arrays.fill(column, bm.get(i, 0) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        imageBitmap.setPixels(column, 0, 1, i, 0, 1, height);
    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

This approach is **really fast even for really big outputs and generates a high quality bitmap**.

Answer (score 2):

There you go,

```
public static Bitmap createBarCode (String codeData, BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat, int codeHeight, int codeWidth) {

    try {
        Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> ();
        hintMap.put (EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

        Writer codeWriter;
        if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
            codeWriter = new QRCodeWriter ();
        } else if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.CODE_128) {
            codeWriter = new Code128Writer ();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException ("Format Not supported.");
        }

        BitMatrix byteMatrix = codeWriter.encode (
            codeData,
            barcodeFormat,
            codeWidth,
            codeHeight,
            hintMap
        );

        int width   = byteMatrix.getWidth ();
        int height  = byteMatrix.getHeight ();

        Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j ++) {
                imageBitmap.setPixel (i, j, byteMatrix.get (i, j) ? Color.BLACK: Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course you can support as many BarcodeFormats as you want, just change the constructor here :

```
Writer codeWriter;
if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
    codeWriter = new QRCodeWriter ();
} else if (barcodeFormat == BarcodeFormat.CODE_128) {
    codeWriter = new Code128Writer ();
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException ("Format Not supported.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Context context = getActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", Text);
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "12345678901");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "UPC_A");
startActivity(intent);
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: what does getActivity() do?

Comment: Two likely definition for `getActivity()` Either `getActivity() in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated with. (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).`
OR
`getActivity() is user-defined.`

Comment: i.e if you are using Fragment then use `getActivity()`. And if you are using Activity  then use `this` keyword to get the Current Activity Context.